# Using Pycharm - Python 3.11 - modules like pandas and tkinter stopped working when I open multiple/previous projects

Tags: python, module, pycharm, virtualenv

While working on a project #1, I opened previous projects (let's say ~3) and even created some new projects to take notes, I had modules that were not working (pandas, tkinter). I did not even have the option to re-install them. They didn't appear to exist. All the while, the modules were perfectly available in *other* projects that were open.

I read that it may have something to do with selecting 'virtual environment'. And so I did create a new project and selected 'Previously configured interpreter' setting which seemed to solve the problem - just annoying.

But I'm wonder a few things:

1. Are modules tied to projects? If so, how/when do they switch?
2. Is there a way I could have just re-configured the NEW projects to make the modules active again.
3. Is there a problem with working with multiple opened projects in Pycharm?

Comment: Packages are tied to the interpreter aka virtual environment. Whenever you create a new project make sure you select the interpreter that contains all the modules you have installed. Settings>project>project interpretter>select that specific interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question - I wondered the same until I took the time to practice [creating a virtual environment](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html&ved=2ahUKEwibvbuiwNSBAxWDQ0EAHZv0CWoQFnoECAwQBQ&usg=AOvVaw1SQ6VGTcJCX7W6wOs1SpnV) via terminal outside of pycharm.

Once I'd done that, I activated it in my terminal and wrote and ran a hello world script which imported the non-native package I was using (pyspark). Now I use that venv any time I need to run pyspark code.

Pycharm creates and activates venvs for you for each project if I'm not mistaken. Keeps projects insulated from each other, but can be confusing at first.

Hope that helps!